# remote connection only works when I'm logged in

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, vncserver

I'm using ubuntu 15 + vncserver for a remote connection. But it only works when i'm physically logged in. Which means if I go to the computer > log in and then try to remotely connect to it - it works. When I'm logged out I'm not able to connect. Is there any way to change that? or at least some terminal command which would allow me to use that?
thank!

Answer (score 0):

1. First install the x11vnc

   sudo apt-get install x11vnc
2. Then, Set the vnc password

   sudo x11vnc -storepasswd  /etc/x11vnc.pass
3. Then open the service file

   sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
4. And, Insert the following text

[Unit]
Description="x11vnc"

Requires=display-manager.service

After=display-manager.service

[Service]

ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 -auth guess -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass

ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc

Restart=on-failure

Restart-sec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

5. Then starts with

   sudo systemctl daemon-reload

   sudo systemctl start x11vnc
6. And make sure the service starts on boot:

   sudo systemctl enable x11vnc

Now x11vnc will start before even you logged in once machine starts

Comment: is there any way to create a separate session? What I mean by this is: when somebody goes physically to the PC and turn on the screen they would see what I'm doing. I would like to avoid this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use x11vnc, try this config in **/etc/init/x11vnc.conf** (replace USER with your actual username):

```
start on login-session-start
script
x11vnc -dontdisconnect -display :0 -auth /home/USER/.Xauthority -notruecolor -noxfixes -shared -forever -rfbport 5900 -bg -o /home/USER/.vnc/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /home/USER/.vnc/passwd
end script
```

(http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-xperms)